# HazelcastJet rolling-aggregation with removing previous data and add new

Tags: hazelcast-jet

We have use case where we are receiving message from kafka that needs to be aggregated. This has to be aggregated in a way that if an updates comes on same id then existing value if any needs to be subtracted and the new value has to be added.

From various forum i got to know that jet doesnt store raw values rather aggregated result and some internal data.

In such case how can i achieve this?

**Example**

```
Balance 1 {id:1, amount:100} // aggregated result 100
Balance 2 {id:2, amount:200} // 300
Balance 3 {id:1, amount:400} // 600 after removing 100 and adding 400
```

I could achieve a simple use where every time add. But i was not able to achieve the aggregation where existing value needs to be subtracted and new value has to be added.

```
rollingAggregation(AggregatorOperations.summingDouble(<login to add remove>))
    .drainTo(Sinks.logger()).
```

1. Balance 1,2,3 are sequnce of messages
2. The comment shows whats the aggregated value at each message performed by jet.
3. My aim is to add new amount (if id comes for the first time) and subtract amount if an updated balance comes i. e. Id is same as earlier.

Comment: You haven't made your use case clear, but I'm guessing you expect your aggregating function to observe the events in the order they occurred. Am I right?

Comment: No, my requirement is simple if a new message comes just add it and if an update on existing message comes then we have to subtract old value because we have an updated value now so subtract the old of value  of that message (remove 100 in this example) and add 400.

Comment: You mean "replace the value"? I find your example very unclear. What are the numbers in the comments?

Comment: Yes replace. Its straightforward, my app received more updated value so the existing value which it aggregated has to be removed (100 should be subtracted ) and the new value 400 should be added

Comment: Is Balance 1 and Balance 2 independent? Your sample is very confusing.

Comment: Balances are sequnces of messages coming each message is indpenedent if id is different, if id is same than its update of an existing message. In this case balance 1 and balance are independent but balance 3 is an update of existing message balance 1 so we need to subtract 100 and add 400

Comment: The numbers in the comment shows the aggregated value on occurrence of each message, done by jet cluster

Comment: Sorry if the question is unclear, do you have any other doubt or can the question be still improved

Comment: So you need the most recent value to win. But how do you determine which value is the most recent, given that the events in the stream will be reordered? Even if they are received in the correct order, Jet is allowed to reorder them in the pipeline.

Comment: Ideally if the key (in this case id) is same it will go to the same member of the jet cluster in that also the order will not be maintained?

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you mean. You want sum of all the amounts, but each ID should be counted once, with the most recent value?

Comment: Yes my aggregation output is sum of all balance.amount with latest amount for all balance

Answer (score 2):

You can try a custom aggregate operation which will emit the previous and currently seen values like this:

```
public static <T> AggregateOperation1<T, ?, Tuple2<T, T>> previousAndCurrent() {
    return AggregateOperation
            .withCreate(() -> new Object[2])
            .<T>andAccumulate((acc, current) -> {
                acc[0] = acc[1];
                acc[1] = current;
            })
            .andExportFinish((acc) -> tuple2((T) acc[0], (T) acc[1]));
}
```

The output should be a Tuple of the form `(previous, current)`. Then you can apply rolling aggregate again to the output. To simplify the problem as input I have a pair of `(id, amount)` pairs.

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
p.drawFrom(Sources.<Integer, Long>mapJournal("map", START_FROM_OLDEST)) // (id, amount)
        .groupingKey(Entry::getKey)
        .rollingAggregate(previousAndCurrent(), (key, val) -> val)
        .rollingAggregate(AggregateOperations.summingLong(e -> {
            long prevValue = e.f0() == null ? 0 : e.f0().getValue();
            long newValue = e.f1().getValue();
            return newValue - prevValue;
        }))
        .drainTo(Sinks.logger());

JetConfig config = new JetConfig();
config.getHazelcastConfig().addEventJournalConfig(new EventJournalConfig().setMapName("map"));
JetInstance jet = Jet.newJetInstance(config);

IMapJet<Object, Object> map = jet.getMap("map");

map.put(0, 1L);
map.put(0, 2L);
map.put(1, 10L);
map.put(1, 40L);

jet.newJob(p).join();
```

This should produce as output: `1, 2, 12, 42`.

Comment: Thank you so much this is what i was looking for. Is there link or doc which has such examples, i saw various git sample code but did not find such example. By just reading documentation i was not able to code for such scenario

Comment: The ref manual has a section on [writing your own aggregate op](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/0.7.2/manual/#implement-your-aggregate-operation). For rolling aggregate combine step is not used so you can ignore that part. Also the Javadoc of AggregateOperation is quite detailed about what each method does.

Comment: I'm trying to follow your example, but in the previousAndCurrent method the exportFinish method keeps throwing an error  Error:(80, 29) java: incompatible types: inference variable R_NEW has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: com.hazelcast.cp.internal.util.Tuple2<T,T>
    lower bounds: com.hazelcast.jet.datamodel.Tuple2<E0,E1>

Comment: Wait, I may have figured it out.  I was importing the wrong Tuple2, I changed it to the com.hazelcast.jet.datamodel.Tuple2 and the error went away.